# Why the android virtual device is not starting?

Tags: android, android-emulator

> Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "E:\Android_Package\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools\emulator.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation

Answer (score 0):

> The requested operation requires elevation

That's telling you that you need to run it as an administrator. It's probably located in a directory whose file permissions or owner is different than what you're currently logged in with.